# Vaadin Flow 24 - Display Yes/No in a Editable Grid Combobox but have a value of 1/0

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm having a problem trying to create an inline comboBox with "Yes" and "No" bound to the `SJRolesQA.getIsAncillary()` value (Integer 1 or 0)

Since I come from a JavaScript/Python background - I first tried something simple:

```
ComboBox cmbIsAncillary = new ComboBox();
cmbIsAncillary.setItems("0","1");
cmbIsAncillary.setItemLabelGenerator("No","Yes");
cmbIsAncillary.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(cmbIsAncillary).bind(SJRolesQA::getIsAncillary, SJRolesQA::setIsAncillary);
isAncillaryColumn.setEditorComponent(cmbIsAncillary);
```

Apparently - not so much. The setItemLabelGenerator complained and the binder complained.

The error in the setItemLabelGenerator was:

```
Method setItemLabelGenerator in class ComboBoxBase<TComponent, Titem, Tvalue> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: ItemLabelGenerator
  found: String, String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where TComponent, TItem and Tvalue are type-variables:
  TComponent extends ComboBoxBse<TComponent, TItem, Tvalue> declared in class ComboBoxBase
  TItem extends Object declared in class ComboBoxBase
  TIValue extends Object declared in class ComboBoxBase
```

the error on the binder is:

```
incompatible types: invalid method reference
  method getIsAncillary in class SJRolesQA cannot be applied to given types
  required: no arguments
  found: Object
  reason: actual and form argument lists differ in length
```

Next, I tried creating a POJO class:

```
    private Integer id;
    private String description;

    public IdName(Integer id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And then use that class like this:

```
ComboBox cmbIsAncillary = new ComboBox();
cmbIsAncillary.setItems(new IdName(1,"Yes"), new IdName(0,"No"));
cmbIsAncillary.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(cmbIsAncillary).bind(SJRolesQA::getIsAncillary, SJRolesQA::setIsAncillary);
isAncillaryColumn.setEditorComponent(cmbIsAncillary);
```

This time the setItems was happy but the binder still didn't work. The error on the binder is:

```
incompatible types: invalid method reference
  method getIsAncillary in class SJRolesQA cannot be applied to given types
  required: no arguments
  found: Object
  reason: actual and form argument lists differ in length
```

Thank you for your patience with a Java/Vaadin newbie!

Comment: If you can: I would recommend to change your type from Integer to boolean to make sure life easier and more straight forward. Once it's a boolean you can replace the Combo box with a Checkbox and everything works out of the box with better usability experience.

Comment: Hi @Knoobie - unfortunately, I can't change the backend datatype. Is there a way to work around it? I also just found out that there a few rows with nulls rather than a 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - after A LOT of spinning in circles, I finally figured out something that works:

COLUMN DEFINITION (adding to grid object):

```
 Grid.Column<SJNotifConfigQA> sentToColumn = grid.addColumn(notification -> {
            String sentToIds = notification.getSentTo();
            List<String> roleNames = parseRoleIds(sentToIds);
            return String.join(", ", roleNames);
        }).setHeader("Sent To");
```

Here's the function `parseRoleIds()`:

```
public List<String> parseRoleIds(String commaSeparatedRoleIds) {
        List<String> roleNames = new ArrayList<>();
        if (commaSeparatedRoleIds != null && !commaSeparatedRoleIds.isEmpty()) {
            String[] roleIdStrings = commaSeparatedRoleIds.split(",");
            for (String roleIdString : roleIdStrings) {
                try {
                    int roleId = Integer.parseInt(roleIdString.trim());
                    // Get the role name using the roleService
                    var roleName = rolesDataService.getRoleById(roleId); // Implement this method in your RoleService
                    roleNames.add(roleName);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Handle invalid role id if necessary
                }
            }
        }
        return roleNames;
    }
```